# Can I add custom rule to rule set of sonarlint

Tags: sonarlint-vs

I am running Sonarlint plugin in Visual studio independently of sonarqube. Can I add custom rule to ruleset of sonarlint??

I tried to check if there is edit/add rules in ruleset.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't add custom rules this way. 
However you can create your own analyzer (see the [how to](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk)) that will take care of your custom rules.